# How to put items from an observable collection in a grid?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

While I was writing an application for Windows Phone 8, I encountered a problem. In ViewModel I have

```
public ObservableCollection<Ball> ListOfBalls { get; set;}
```

Every Ball has their row number and column number.

In View I have specified `Grid.Row` into which I want to put a grid (10 rows x 10 columns) and then I want to put one ball from ListOfBalls in every grid cell.

So, that is `View`:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="GamePlayGrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- I've tried to add ItemsControl here -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I try to define Grid (10 rows x 10 columns) and then in scope of this grid I tried to add `ItemsControl` with `DataTemplate`, but I'm not sure if it's right, because during execution I got some unhandled exception... How can I fix this?

Comment: please try to post a sample code  of your project  it's  the best way  to provide you  with  the best solution

Comment: Please check an answer or add more help to us

Answer (score 0):

**Edited,** from your code, Added Image

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfBalls}"/>
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
             <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="{Binding Path=BallImageName}"/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding BallName}"/>
            <StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl> 
  </Grid>
```

BallImageName is a property of ball image, Please add the source of the located file. (e.g:"Images/myimage.png")

Comment: I've added it, but there is error
The type 'ListView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581%28v=vs.105%29.aspx ListView doesn't exist in WP8

Comment: But i don't want to make them constant size. I want to make this looking good in every resolution.

Comment: Then add them a size, with binding, and calculate the optimal size in your codebehing, for example

Comment: What about creating Image in codebehind and is there any way to locate it in grid row/column by some property ?

Comment: Please chechk the modified version of my Ansver